# I want to get multiple types as query parameters by using .split(',') in WHERE IN()

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to get multiple types as query parameters by using type.split(',') in WHERE IN().

I have service.js and DAO.js files. And I tried this like below.

service.js

```
const productTypeSort = async (name, type, productSort, page) => {
  const sort = orderBy(productSort);
  const categoryType = getCategoryType(name, type);

  return await productsDao.productTypeSort(categoryType, sort, page);
};

const getCategoryType = (name, type) => {
const filter = type.toString().split(',')
  const FilterType = {
    category: `WHERE c.name = "${name}"`,
    categoryType: `WHERE c.name = "${name}" AND t.name IN ("${filter}")`,
  };

  if (name && type) {
    return FilterType.categoryType;
  } else if (name) {
    return FilterType.category;
  }

  return '';
};
```

DAO.js

```
const productTypeSort = async (categoryType, sort, page) => {
  const products = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT
      c.name AS category,
      t.name AS type,
      pr.name,
      pr.description,
      price_origin,
      pr.created_at,
      count(*) OVER() AS totalCount
    FROM products pr
    JOIN category c ON c.id = pr.category_id
    JOIN product_types t ON t.id = pr.type_id
    ${categoryType}
    GROUP BY pr.id
    ${sort}
    LIMIT ?, 9`,
    [(page - 1) * 9]
  );
  return products;
};
```

and the query I sent is as follows.

```
?name=abc&type=aaa,bbb&sort=review&page=1
```

But this returns an empty data column.

```
{
     "data": []
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the location of .split(',') is wrong? I need help.

Comment: Why is the content of the `IN` operator wrapped in quotes (`IN ("...")`)?

Comment: [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) ([explained](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `filter` array is `["aaa,bbb"]` and that ends up making a query string which looks like:

```
WHERE t.name IN ("aaa,bbb")
```

What you need is to map each value in `filter` to a single-quote enclosed string, and remove the double-quotes from the query:

```
filter = type.split(',').map(s => `'${s}'`)
// ...
categoryType: `WHERE c.name = "${name}" AND t.name IN (${filter})`,
```

This will give you something that looks like:

```
WHERE t.name IN ('aaa','bbb')
```

which should give you your desired result.

You should take note of what @Andreas referred to in their comment; you should preferably be using prepared statements rather than injecting user input directly into your query. If someone sent `type="); DROP table products --`
you would get a nasty surprise.

Comment: The way you told me was able to get the results I wanted! Thank you very much!

Comment: @ggyoE no worries - I'm glad I could help. Please do look into prepared statements.